# JSP Include textfile if it isn't empty

Tags: jsp, include, text-files

I have a jsp page that is supposed to include the content of a multiline text file (wrapped up in some markup) if, *and only if*, there is content in that file.

The file always exists, but some times it will be empty, and some times it will have content.

I was thinking of reading the file into a string (or stringBuffer?), and then test the length of it. But since it is a multiline file, my code breaks up on linebreaks.

P.S. I'm a jsp n00b, so bear over with me, if this is a stupidly easy (or impossible) task! :)

Comment: Actually it isn't stupid but you should avoid having logic on pages, you coukd have a servlet method to read the file and return its content and then on the page you just test if the content is empty or not

Comment: You set the text content in a hidden div, and then check the length of the content using javascript. If it's not empty just show the div or dump the content to the location, where you originally wanted to show. If you can share the code it would be helpful.